# ElasticSearch on concatination of multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data where phone number is in parts. Therefore I created it as an array(object). But I want to search on the complete phone number now.

```
"Phone":{
  "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
      "first" : {
        "type” : "text"
      },
      "second": {
        "type" : "text"
      }
   }
}
```

Now if I have three records, [{"first" : "123", "second" = "456"}, {"first" : "456", "second" = "123"}, {"first" : "412", "second" = "356"}]. It should search on records like "123456", "456123", "412356". And should give 3 records for query "123".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/copy-to.html) fields or create an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/ingest.html) that creates a single field of those different numbers and also enriches the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But copy_to is more of a "merge two fields" than "concatenate two fields", "copy_to": [ "field_1", "field_2" ]